# php@Azure Website: Can't write to %TMP%

Tags: php, iis, azure-web-app-service

We're trying to write cache files from php to an azure website's %TMP% dir (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1websitename\Temp) and getting permission denied errors.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: What is your azure website name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was between Kudo and the actual site. For Kudo, the %tmp% variable points to C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1websitename\Temp while the site's variable is C:\DWASFiles\Sites\websitename\Temp

You don't have permission to access the site's folder from kudo, and vice-verse.